# When does recv() return?

Tags: c, sockets, stream, swift, recv

I have made a server and a client using sockets. My server is written in c and runs on my raspberry pi and my client is written in Swift and is running on my Mac/iPhone.

What i don't get is when my servers recv() function execute what i have sent from my client? If i send like 0-10 bytes it doesn't return from recv() function before i close the connection. But if I send 100+ bytes it executes immediately.

I would like my server to return from recv() every time i write a message from my client.

Here is my servers recv() function:

```
//Receive a message from client
while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
{
    printf("%s", client_message);
}
```

Here is my Clients write method:

```
func SendMsg(msg:String) -> Int{
    return outputStream!.write(msg, maxLength: countElements(msg))
}
```

Everything works fine beside I'm not in control of when my server executes my messages.

Comment: I don't know if Swift sends the string terminator that is needed by the C code, so you might have a possible case of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the server.

Comment: I have made the client in C also. from there i got the same behaviour. are you talking about the \0 end char?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `recv` and not the `printf` that buffers the data ? Try adding a `'\n'` at the end of the `printf` format string.

Comment: Yes it's the terminating `'\0'` character I talk about. If the client doesn't send it, the server needs to add it.

Comment: Oh and regarding the comment from @SanderDeDycker, you have to remember that output to `stdout` by default is *line buffered*. Add a newline of manually flush the output buffer.

Comment: Yes because every time i hit the "Send button" i dont get anything printed before i close the connection. newline char or not.

Comment: Note well about the null-terminator. Since TCP is a streaming service, recv() may return with 'intermediate data' that does not include any null added to the sent message by the client.  You must add a null at the server end, at client_message[read_size], to be sure of avoiding the printf("%s...) UB.  To do this, you may have to request that recv() return 1999 bytes, or declare the buffer 2001], to make room.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output to `stdout` is by default line buffered, so when using `printf`, make sure there is a newline character (`'\n'`) at the end. If the message itself doesn't already contain a newline, then :

```
printf("%s\n", client_message);
```

As a side note : also make sure that `client_message` is properly null terminated before passing it to `printf`, or you might run into undefined behavior (ref. @JoachimPileborg's comment). If you can't ensure null termination, this would do the trick too :

```
printf("%.*s\n", read_size, client_message);
```

Answer (score 2):

The server doesn't get the message because the client hasn't sent it.

You need to `fflush` the outputStream on the client side!

Comment: I added the newline char to my printf and it works now. are you sure my client don't send the message then?

Comment: If the outputStream is line buffered, then adding a newline will cause the buffer to flush (implicit flush).